# calling program looks in snap folder

Tags: apt, snap

I'm running ubuntu, and have just attempted to install john the ripper:

```
Nicolay@dom:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                         
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                       
Get:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                       
Ign:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                             
Hit:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                          
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal InRelease                   
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Get:10 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [550 kB]
Get:11 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,294 kB]
Get:12 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [284 kB] 
Get:13 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [866 kB]          
Get:15 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [642 kB]           
Get:16 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [362 kB]
Get:17 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B] 
Get:18 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.4 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [29.0 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63.6 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 4,433 kB in 1s (3,345 kB/s)            
Reading package lists... Done
```

so this looks like it works.
But now when I try to invoke the program:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/PassCracking$ john
bash: /snap/bin/john: No such file or directory
```

It looks in the `/snap` folder. Why can this be?

it might be worth noting that I previously had  john the ripper isntalled via snap, but uninstalled it